# Android relativeLayout: How to make button take bottom port of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I was wondering can I create a button that would take the bottom portion of the screen as seen here:

[image]

I have tried to play with the alignment and margins, but to no avail:

[image]

Another question that I had was why my movie poster is not aligning to the left of the top text properly? As can be seen, it's a bit to the right. I had attempted to drag it into place.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abushawish.randommovie.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Black Hawk Down"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/bhd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="New Movie Suggestion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-50dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom= "-20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove these.

`android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"`
`android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`
`android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`
`android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`
`android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"`

They add padding to the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by removing the padding and margins in order to have a simple layout.
When it is ok, you can put back the padding & margins one by one to see which ones are ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the buttons parent layout, then your button will align with the edges of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abushawish.randommovie.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
```

If you still want to have padding for the other objects add them in a separate layout with padding.

**Edit**

To put the picture in the middle add

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try android:gravity="bottom" and in the relative layout add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

This will give u the intended look.. and yes, don't give weight to children of `RelativeLayout`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="New Movie Suggestion" />
```